# Is this the correct way to set and get a string value using persistance in GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is this the correct way to set and get a string value using persistance in GAE ?

I'm receiving error :

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException: No entity was found matching the key: jsonString("jsonString")
```

Adding to store :

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("jsonString", "jsonString");
Entity urlEntity = new Entity("jsonString" , key);
urlEntity.setProperty("urlVal", urlVal);

com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key urlEntityKey = datastore.put(urlEntity);
```

Returning from store :

```
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("jsonString", "jsonString");
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Entity entity = datastore.get(key);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review the below code, also you can find more details on how to use the app engine datastore API by reviewing the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/index.html?com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity.html).  Also review the notes in the [Datastore Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html#Introducing_the_Java_Datastore) document.

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity e = new Entity("data");
e.setProperty("jsonString", "myValue");
Key key = ds.put(e);
Entity entity = ds.get(key);
System .out.println(entity);
```

Comment: but how can I keep a reference to Key object created at : Key key = ds.put(e); Sure this code works when putting & getting are done sequentially, but what if I need to access the data when I do not know what the Key value is ?

Comment: Query for it, documentation [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html), You could also consider using [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) if you are new to the datastore, it's much simpler.